# How to obtain URL parameter using jquery in case insensitive way

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to obtain a URL parameter in a case insensitive way using jquery?

Essentially, I'm looking to do something like  `$.url('?someparameter');`, where it would match both `http:\\www.test.com?someparameter=ABC` or
`http:\\www.test.com?SOMEparAMeter=ABC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase). This function converts any string to lowercase.

Comment: `.toUpperCase()` for cruise control :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression where you set the case-insensitive flag.

[Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) -- scroll down to "Advanced Searching With Flags"

Please take a look at: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

The line to adapt to your needs is as follows:

```
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)", "i");
//"i" for case-insensitive
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt use jQuery, just javascript. But it addresses the question in general.

The problem w/ ucasing the entire ULR is you may be keying off the value to look up an HTML element.

why there is not a  collection of keys in URL.searchParams, I do not know, but there is not.
Below is a function i wrote that will find a key and  return a value.

I am just barely literate in regEx, so I am sure there is a better regEx that can pull the
value out and omit trailing key value pairs.

```
 function getParm_CI(parm) { 
                var str = window.location.href;
                 var rgx = new RegExp('\\b' + parm + '=.*\\b', 'gi');

                //this gets an array of matches
                var aMatches = str.match(rgx);
                if (aMatches == null) return;
                var parmVal = aMatches[0].substring(parm.length + 1);

                        //we shouldnt, but make sure there are not trailing parms
                var idx = parmVal.indexOf('&');
                        //alert('amp:' + idx);
                if (idx > -1) parmVal = parmVal.substring(0, idx);
                return parmVal;
        }
```

usage would be like this

```
var topic = getParm_CI('SOMEparAMeter');
```